# Replace a Portion of NSMutableData with a NSString

Tags: ios, ascii, nsdata

I have some `NSMutableData` holding some `ASCII` code.
I would like to replace some bytes in a specific range with other bytes made up of an `NSString`:

```
NSString *myString = @"\r"
const char *myChar = [myString UTF8String];
[myData replaceBytesInRange:myRange withBytes:&myChar];
```

Now, when logging myData I get different values for the exchanged byte every time I run the App! Aren't I supposed to get <0D>?!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not parse the NSData to NSString and than replace the String with your new UTF8 String.

Comment: Because it cannot get converted back properly. My data holds 256 ASCII while, NSString can only handle 128 (NSASCIIStringEncoding). Or am I missing another encoding?

Comment: you parse some MS Documents?

Comment: You mean Microsoft created documents? Yes.

Comment: yes, i mean Microsoft documents. Alternative you can search for a C or C++ wrapper. There a many on the market.